# Storage usage steadily climbing in Postgres database managed by Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, postgresql

I stood up a new SQL database a few days ago on Google Cloud for testing some application. The application is fairly basic and just uses Postgres with simple tables and basic SQL queries. I noticed today that the storage usage of the database has been steadily climbing -- even when the application is not running.

Here is the storage usage for the past six hours:

[image: storage usage graph]

Curiously my tables are all around 8mb:

```
     name      |       owner       |  size
---------------+-------------------+---------
 my_db         | postgres          | 8417 kB
 cloudsqladmin | cloudsqladmin     | 8249 kB
 postgres      | cloudsqlsuperuser | 8169 kB
 template1     | cloudsqlsuperuser | 8169 kB
 template0     | cloudsqladmin     | 8025 kB
```

Without knowing too much more, what could be going on here? There are no scheduled jobs, the DB hasn't had any custom configuration, etc. It was simply stood up, the database was created with my ORM, and some data was inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was caused by the [Point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/restore#tips-pitr). Disabling this feature will result in storage usage dropping significantly and not rising again.

From what others have mentioned off-site, the regular 5 minute intervals of backups may be caused by point-in-time snapshots which are stored in the instance disk and would even out storage usage after about 7 days.

Comment: Which automated backups are you talking about? [Cloud SQL automated](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backups#automated-backups) are supposed to happen only during a 4hr window, and should not count for the storage usage of the instance, as mentioned in the [Where backups are stored](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/backups#where_backups_are_stored) section.

Comment: @pessolato yes, the automated backups were what I disabled. I'm not sure exactly what the deal was but I *only* disabled them and the storage usage dropped. Someone on reddit mentioned point-in-time snapshots, which I haven't investigated yet.

Comment: after testing I confirmed it is the [Point-in-time recovery](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/backup-recovery/restore#tips-pitr) feature that causes the storage usage to increase every 5 minutes. Keep in mind that you can keep the automated backups without having this feature enable, in which case they would behave as I explained in my previous comment. If you update your answer to make this clear, I'll be sure to upvote it as well.

Comment: @pessolato thanks for taking the time to reproduce, verify, and edit the answer.